# C++ templates: choice between static and dynamic allocations (a la Eigen)

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-memory-allocation, compile-time, static-allocation

Eigen, the linear algebra library written in C++, uses a clever technique: template parameters (for example the dimensions of a matrix) that are not known at compile time can take the special value Dynamic, which means that run-time values will be expected. See here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title2
How standard is this technique in C++? Did the Eigen team come up with it or borrow the idea from another project?
I'm working on a C++ solver for nonconvex optimization and I'm thinking about borrowing it.
Thanks,
Charlie

Comment: it is now used in `std::span` and `std::mdspan`

Comment: I suddenly became unsure if I answered the wrong thing so I deleted my answer.

Comment: I would say it is getting more common, but still niche.  Another way things like this were/are handled is to use a `allocator` that can allocate statically but if too much is requested then it falls back to dynamic allocation.

Comment: `std::vector` (all containers tbh) has an "allocator" template parameter. With that you can provide a type with a static buffer and avoid runtime allocations (you'll probably want to restrict smh or provide an upstream resource like pmr allocators do). Can't speak for the creators of Eigen but this is commonly done. The design features that Eigen actually advertises are "Expression templates, CRTP, Evaluators, Meta unroller, Cost model, SIMD, reductions". These are more intricate patterns, but they also had names when they where chosen.